# Changing src of an iframe combined with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, iframe, setinterval, src

I'm trying to process my JS array of download links, so that they open in an iframe for **delay** miliseconds each to make user capable of clicking on download link. The issue is, as a link loads into the iframe, it suddenly & for no reason jumps into the main window, just like if I simply redirected the page. Then script stops because I'm at the location of the first array link. Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="
var delay = document.getElementById('delay').value;
var arr = ['link1.html','link2.gtml','link3.html','link4.html'];
var i = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
document.getElementById('iframe').src = arr[i];
if (i+1<arr.length) {i++;} else {clearInterval(loop);}
}, delay);
"><div class="button" align="center" style="font-size: 14px;">Start the batch</div></a>  
<br>
Loading interval: <input type="text" size="2" id="delay" value="15000"> miliseconds
<br>
<iframe id="iframe" style="width: 99%; height: 400px; border: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.5);" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you sure those pages you have do not use some sort of protection to disallow loading in iframes? For example google has one.

Comment: Really bad idea to put that much code into an onclick handler. Extract it into a function and call the function from `onclick`, or better yet, attach an event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly got your question, but what I know regarding your question, that when you change src attribute in iframe, it updates your browser history state, so try, not update src attribute, but recreate iframe again:

```
var loop = setInterval(function(){
 var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
 var parent = document.getElementById('iframe').parentNode;
 parent.removeChild(iframe);
 var newIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
 newIframe.src = arr[i];
 parent.appendChild(newIframe);
 if (i+1<arr.length) {i++;} else {clearInterval(loop);}
}, delay);
```

Comment: Thank you. Anyway, it doesn't seem to work. There is no effect taken on the iframe if I use this method. I still have to look for a solution...